# Convert datetime in MVC4 view causes an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have a **content entity model** in my project that i created it by EF6.

```
 public partial class Content
{
    public Content()
    {
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Brief { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string MainText { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime DateOfPublish { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string SmallImageUrl { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string BigImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string KeyWords { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime DateOfExpire { get; set; }
    public string AutherUserName { get; set; }
    public long VisitVCount { get; set; }
    public string Visible { get; set; }
    public int ContentGroupId { get; set; }
    public long LikeCount { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentGroup ContentGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see i have a column **DateOfPublish** and the type of is **Datetime** .

I want to convert the date **DateOfPublish** to persian date with this function :

```
public string ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime? datetime)
        {
            string date;
            DateTime dt;

            if (!datetime.HasValue) return "";
            dt = datetime.Value;          
            string year = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetYear(dt));
            string month = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt));
            string day = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));
            if (month.Length == 1)
            {
                month = "0" + Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt));
            }
            if (day.Length == 1)
            {
                day = "0" + Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(dt));
            }
 Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(dt)) + "/" +

            date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
            return date;
        }
```

So i call this function in my View (**content view**) so i tried to show the date in Persian using this function.So i passed the English date to my function as you can see here:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    DateConverter objconverter = new DateConverter();
}
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(objconverter.ConvertToPersianToShow(modelItem => item.DateOfPublish ))
    </td>
```

But i got this error:

```
Argument type "lambda expression" is not assignable to parameter type 'system.nullable<system.datatime>'
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => objconverter.ConvertToPersianToShow(item.DateOfPublish ))
```

Comment: I get this error now on that line that you said: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item => objconverter.ConvertToPersianToShow(item.DateOfPublish ))
```